# Indentaion Error

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Я хочу создать бота в Telegram, но не могу по сколько присутствует такая ошибка.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'with' statement on line 10
```

А вот и сам код.

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import python_weather



bot = Bot(token="5946210024:AAGkNfgBnFcDBNQLZIEoKVtlZCikxe7VNis")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
async with python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL)as client:


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def process_start_command(message):
    weather = await client.get(message.text)
    celsius = (weather.current.temperature - 32) * 5 / 9

    resp_msg = weather.location_name + "\n"
    resp_msg += f"Текущая температура:{celsius}\n"

    await message.answer(message.text)

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Отступы перепроверьте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы не сделали отступ после объявления функции:

```
async def process_start_command(message):
```

и сделали перед ней.

Чтобы код работал, вам нужно изменить его следующим образом:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import python_weather

bot = Bot(token="TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def process_start_command(message):
    async with python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL) as client:
        weather = await client.get(message.text)
    celsius = (weather.current.temperature - 32) * 5 / 9

    resp_msg = weather.location_name + "\n"
    resp_msg += f"Текущая температура:{celsius}\n"
    #resp_msg +=

    await message.answer(message.text)
    #await client.close()

@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

---

UPD: Также была проблема, связанная с неправильным использованием контекстного менеджера, нужно было перенести строчку:

```
async with python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.IMPERIAL) as client:
```

в тело функции, перед получением результата в `weather`.

Comment: Не помогло, по итогу получилась другая ошибка:                                
    @dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'with' statement on line 10

Comment: можете указать её здесь? возможно, вместе удастся найти решение

Comment: Пересоздал вопрос

Comment: ошибка в 10 строчке. вам нужно убрать контекстный менеджер со словом `with`, который там есть сейчас, и вставить  его перед строчкой `weather = await client.get(message.text)`, вставив перед ней табуляцию. сейчас отредактирую ответ

Comment: @MatveyLitovskiy исправил, можете смотреть

Comment: Все, работает, спасибо))))

Comment: @MatveyLitovskiy пожалуйста! отметьте мой ответ как правильный, если вам нетрудно)